# ORA-01031 :An attempt was made to perform a database operation without the necessary privileges

Tags: database, plsql, triggers, privileges

create or replace TRIGGER pdb_startup

AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter pluggable database all open';

END;

i try to made this trigger but i have insufficient privileges

Answer (score 1):

To create a system trigger you must have the "`ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER`" privilege.

While I don't work with PDB/CDB arrangements, what you are trying to do looks a bit strange. Normally we control database status through scripts external to the database, not in triggers. Are you sure this is the appropriate way to open your PDBs? I would also want to know whether this could deadlock on the library cache. At any rate, any DDL would require that a trigger be declared with the `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma.